# GCP Cloud Data Loss Prevention Request Violates Constraint

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm new to the Security Command Center (SCC) and Data Loss Prevention (DLP). I'm trying to create a job in DLP to check if there is any PII in a BigQuery table, but I'm getting the following error upon creation:

```
Request violates constraint constraints/gcp.resourceLocations on the project resource.
Learn more https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/defining-locations.
```

[image: DLP job creation error]

On the organization level, there's an **organization policy** (inherited in my project) allowing resources to be created in **Europe only** due to GDPR. I suspect that maybe DLP runs in **some other region** (US maybe) and that's why I'm getting this error.

I can't seem to be able to choose where does the job run in the options while creating the job, and I can't seem to find anything about this in the documentation. Any idea why am I getting this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is copied from [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1026039/583781).

Your organization policy is not allowing DLP to run the job, at this moment the DLP API is blocked by this "constraints/gcp.resourceLocations" and there's no workaround at the moment. However, there's a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155032238) to have the possibility to set a specific location rather than using "global", which is what in fact is causing this issue.